PyInstaller not including image and sounds files
I am trying to make an executable file with PyInstaller that includes two images and two mp3 files. All of my files are in the same directory as my main.py.
Here is what I am putting into the cmd:
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "LifeOrBath.jpg;." --add-data "MainSound.mp3;." --add-data "BATH.png;." --add-data "BooWomp.mp3;." main.py

The main.exe comes out correctly, but I get a error when I run it:
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource: Unresolved error code 0x80070002 (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Why would they not be included when making the executable?

The files are probably included, it's more likely that you tried to load them as local files, which is obviously not doable since they are not actual physical files. You should either use Qt resources or use pyinstaller methods to access the "frozen" data.

how are you accessing them in your main.py?

@Samuel See [ask]. Post a [mre].

There is nothing wrong with your pyinstaller command. The files are definitely included.
If you are not sure whether the files are included, you can delete --onefile and run the command again. You will see the files in the generated main folder.
DirectShowPlayerService::doSetUrlSource This error shows up because you tried to play videos with QMediaPlayer but hadn't got a proper video decoder installed.
Intall the LAV Filter and the problem should be solved. Here is the link to download the LAV Filter.

